# Create type copies

Tags: c++, c++11

How do you create type copies? For example, how do I create types `Mass`, `Acceleration` and `Force` which are not implicitly convertible to `double`(or any other numeric type), but otherwise have all the characteristics of a `double`. This would allow a compile-time input validity check for this function:

```
Force GetForceNeeded(Mass m, Acceleration a);
```

ensuring that `GetForceNeeded` can only be called with arguments of type `Mass` and `Acceleration`.

Of course, I could achieve this by manually creating a copy of the type:

```
class Force final
{
public:
//overload all operators
private:
double value;
};
```

but this is cumbersome. Is there a generic solution?

Comment: Maybe a template? Or use Boost.Units?

Comment: @KerrekSB But how do I expose all the operations defined? Say I want to do it for a `string`?

Comment: @Columbo Reading up on strong typedefs! This might do it. Thanks!

Comment: Typedefs can be used.

Comment: You are not providing any value by wrapping doubles into classes, beside a name. Use typedefs as suggested.

Comment: @Samuel That's not true at all. As explained in the question, they provide semantic checks. Just look at the `GetForceNeeded` function. If the inputs were both `double`, I could end up switching the `Mass` and `Acceleration` arguments and the compiler would be happy. (Ok, for this function it makes no difference because `F=ma`, but the point stands.)

Comment: @Pradhan. Then you need implicit conversions: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast

Comment: The downvotes here are quite funny btw - after Columbo pointed me to strong typedefs, I came across [this well-received question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211210/using-strong-typedef-as-a-more-lightweight-alternative-to-boost-parameter-librar) which is along similar lines.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/243154/c-strongly-typed-typedef

Comment: Kerrek SB had the right solution: Boost.Units. You specifically do NOT want the same operations. It doesn't make sense to add a Mass and an Acceleration, but it does make sense to multiply them. Don't try to work this out yourself, Boost.Units allows all sensible operations and only those (which admittedly is a bit of an issue in fluid mechanics)

Comment: @MSalters The variables I chose to illustrate are a bit misleading I guess. I am not trying to do this with physical units or dimensional analysis. I am looking for just a way to create a new type which behaves exactly like another type but isn't implicitly convertible to it. I would want to be able to do this `using_strong EmailAddress = std::string;`, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As many commentators have pointed out, one solution is to use [BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) which provides all the features requested in the question. And here's example usage from their docs:

```
#include <boost/serialization/strong_typedef.hpp>


BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, a)
void f(int x);  // (1) function to handle simple integers
void f(a x);    // (2) special function to handle integers of type a 
int main(){
    int x = 1;
    a y;
    y = x;      // other operations permitted as a is converted as necessary
    f(x);       // chooses (1)
    f(y);       // chooses (2)
}    typedef int a;
```

There is a [proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3515.pdf) to add opaque typedefs to C++1y.

(I am leaving this answer as I can't find an exact dupe. Please flag if that isn't the case.)