# Enforce type safety in C++ without using extra classes

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, type-safety

I am somewhat familiar with type safety, and have used it successfully before in methods which receive several parameters of the same type (bool) to avoid confusion. For example:

```
// Old version of the method
void sendPackage(bool sendImmediately, bool dividePacket);

// Type safe version
enum SendImmediatelyPreference
{
    SEND_IMMEDIATELY,
    DO_NOT_SEND_IMMEDIATELY
};

enum PacketDivisionPreference
{
    DIVIDE_PACKET,
    DO_NOT_DIVIDE_PACKET
};

void sendPackage(
    SendImmediateltPreference immediatePref,
    PacketDivisionPreference divisionPref);
```

So the cryptic `sendPackage(true, false)` becomes `sendPackage(SEND_IMMEDIATELY, DO_NOT_DIVIDE_PACKET)`.

The problem is that this is only an option for `bool`. I have a method that accepts several `std::vector<std::string>` and I'd like to minimise the posibility of the user inputting the arguments in the wrong order.

I can think of creating different classes which contains an `std::vector<std::string>` and either override tons of the `std::vector` methods or expose the internal vector.

Is there an easier way, some sort of typedef which enforces type safety? Using `boost` would be okay.

Comment: See boost strong typedef http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html

Comment: I'd take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34287842/c-strongly-typed-using-and-typedef). C++ doesn't have strongly typed typedefs, unfortunately, but you can try to work around that.

Comment: I don't know how to get type safety without using different types. I suppose you could use `std::pair` like this: `struct type1{}; struct type2{}; std::pair<type1, std::vector<std::string>> v1; std::pair<type2, std::vector<std::string>> v2;`

Comment: Thanks for your answers, @BartekBanachewicz and @RichardCritten. `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` seems to be what I'm looking for, but it's good to know about its limitations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html) is precisely a typedef which enforces type safety.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9211895/2891462) provides some caveats related to using this strong typedef for just a function, and argues that the types should be used all over the code to prevent unnecessary castings.

Answer (score 2):

How about an alternative approach using named parameters? There are several ways of going about this in C++ described [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/marcoarena.wordpress.com/2014/12/16/bring-named-parameters-in-modern-cpp/amp/). The tag approach using a tuple looks reasonable.  There is also [boost parameter](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/parameter/doc/html/index.html).

This doesn't offer strong type safety, but you could argue that the user is just as likely to call the wrong constructor to make their type safe object as they are to use the wrong tag when calling your function.  This situation is less likely to occur if the types are used throughout your application vs defined only for one particular function.

See also the discussion of boost strong typedef vs parameter for a similar purpose [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211210/using-strong-typedef-as-a-more-lightweight-alternative-to-boost-parameter-librar).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood you correctly, but maybe this can help:

```
enum SendImmediatelyPreference : bool  // allows only 2 options:
{
  DO_NOT_SEND_IMMEDIATELY,  // false
  SEND_IMMEDIATELY          // true
}
```

Comment: No, sorry, this doesn't answer my question (which is related to vectors, although ideally it would be a generla answer)

Answer (score 0):

What about creating a class that inherits (public) from std::vector to have a strong typecheck. The advantage is that you only need to rewrite constructors..

You can also regroup your parameters in a std::unordered_map>, to implement argument as a dict (like  in python, or javascript)

Comment: I thought of this possibility, but I do not like extending STL (although maybe I should be more flexible).

Answer (score 0):

I like to bundle the parameters in a config class or struct. For example:

```
struct SendOptions
{
    bool send_immediately = false;
    bool divide_packet = false;
    // ...
};

void sendPackage(SendOptions options);
```

This has the additional advantage the extra options can be added later without needing to change the interface of `sendPackage(SendOptions)`.

**This does not increase type safety** but it does help to prevent errors (especially if there are a lot of parameters), which is probably the goal you're trying to achieve.