# What should I use instead of -Wconversion?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, warnings

I'm introducing new types in my program, such as `tileno_i`, `pageno_i` and `blockno_u` where I used to have only `int` or `unsigned`, the idea being to communicate more clearly what sort of value a function takes or returns.

I had hope to use g++'s `-Wconversion` flag to spot places where some local variables should be converted to the new types as well, but I end up with lots of situations requiring useless casting, such as

```
for (tileno_i i = 0 ; i < size(); i += 4) {
//                                  ^
// warning: conversion to tileno_i {aka short unsigned int} from 'int' may alter its value
```

Is there a flag similar to `Wconversion` that would let me catch errors without going to assume that things are automatically promoted to `int`s as soon as I do arithmetic on them?

Comment: Whether you assume it or not, promotions happen, as part of the arithmetic conversions.

Comment: agreed, but it makes tracking these new types impossible within the ton of warning coming from external headers. I'd also like to avoid killing the readability with extra casts all over the place. Plus, if I always end up with `var = (tileno_t) arg + 1`, that wouldn't check that arg was a tileno_t in first place.

Comment: That might say something about the design of those new types.

Comment: Please not that POSIX reserves all type names ending in `_t` for the implementation, so naming your own types like that is ill adviced.

Comment: Have a look at Boost's Stong typedef see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211210/using-strong-typedef-as-a-more-lightweight-alternative-to-boost-parameter-librar

Comment: What does `4u` give you?

Comment: @Niall: it says "conversion to 'tileno_t {aka short unsigned int} from 'unsigned int' may alter its value". Unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry, forgot there is no suffix for `short` - don't think a custom one will help either

Comment: Why use `short`s anyway?

Comment: tiles number are ultimately written into 16-bit, low-level video memory areas. So it (should) be better to keep them in u16 (short unsigned). Target platform is NintendoDS, 4MiB data, 16KiB stack.

Answer (score 0):

My best workaround so far is to temporarily typedef xxx_t to something else than integers (e.g. an enum) so that the 'type errors' due to not-yet-converted lines trigger something at a higher error level than what requires -Wconversion.